# Android/Xamarin/C#: Resource Id not constant anymore

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I used to work on an Android/Xamarin project for Android 4.4, API Level 19 that contains an activity with the following code:

```
private void RadioButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

    switch (rb.Id)  
    {
        case Resource.Id.radioButton1:
        ...
```

The last time I looked at the project a couple of month ago, this used to work just fine. Now I want to continue working on the project for Android 8.0, API Level 26, but when I opened it in Visual Studio 2017 I got the compiler error `(field)int ResourceId.RadioButton1 A constant value is expected`.

Now this is not a problem in itself, as I can always use `if (rb.Id == ...)` instead of `switch/case`, but I would like to know why all of a sudden `Resource.Id.radioButton1` is not recognized as a constant anymore, even though it is declared as such in `Resource.Designer.cs`:

```
public const int radioButton1 = 2131165244;
```

Has anyone else encountered something similar?

EDIT: Even stranger is that the project builds without complaint, but deployment is not possible due to the said error.

EDIT: It seems that the build process generates another `Resource.Designer.cs` file which is put into a folder `obj\Debug\designtime`. Once the file exists, the activities source code refers for the `Id` declarations to this new file and not to the original `Resource.Designer.cs` in the `Resources` folder.

However, all `Ids` in the new file are `static` and not `const` (which of course is the reason for the compiler error that prompted this question in the first place) and moreover they are all set to zero.

Are there any Android/Xamarin experts out there who can explain what is going on here? Might that even be a bug in Visual Studio 2017/Xamarin?

EDIT: Here is a link shedding some light on this topic: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19369/compiling-resource-ids-static-vs-const

What I don't get is this: Why did the above code work at all considering that this problem is known since 2014?

Comment: What is your VS version? You could refer refer to: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1731